# Prove that a function grows faster than another

Tags: functions, algorithms, asymptotics

I have the following functions:

$ f = {\sqrt n}\left(\log n\right)^4$, 
$ g= n\log n$

I know that $\,\,\, f=O(g)\,\,$ but I when I try to prove it I find that $\,\,\, g=O(f)\,\,$ which is not true..

The following is the proof:

${\sqrt n}\left(\log n\right)^4\quad?\quad n\log n$

$\dfrac{{\sqrt n}\left(\log n\right)^4}{n\log n}\quad?\quad\dfrac{n\log n}{n\log n}\qquad\text{(dividing both sides by }n\log n)$

$\dfrac{\left(\log n\right)^3}{\sqrt n}\quad?\quad1$

Can someone help? how can I prove this correctly?

Comment: I don't see the problem. $g\notin\mathcal O(f)$ since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\log n)^3}{n^{1/2}}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

That's because it is not true that
$g = O(f)$.

To see this:

$\dfrac{g}{f}
=\dfrac{n\log n}{\sqrt{n}(\log(n)^4}
=\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{(\log(n)^3}
\to \infty
$
since
$\dfrac{\log n}{n^c}
\to \infty
$ for any $c > 0$.